# Improper multivariable integrals

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, improper-integrals

I'm having trouble with the integral $$\iiint_{1\le x^2+y^2+z^2 }\frac{\mathrm{d}x~\mathrm{d}y~\mathrm{d}z}{xyz}$$

this is what I've done so far:

$$\lim_{b\to +\infty}\int_1^b \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\pi}\frac {r^2\sin(\psi)~\mathrm{d}\psi~\mathrm{d}\theta ~\mathrm{d}r}{r^3\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)\cos(\psi)\sin²(\psi)}$$

but I'm lost. Besides, $\cos(x)$ and $\sin(x)$ are zero in many points of the domain, do I have to consider those too? Any hints please?

Comment: Note that the radial integral comes out as $\log r$, which blows up as $b\to\infty$. So there's more than one mystery with this integral. Where did it come up?

Comment: @Semiclassical: It is in the Williamson-Trotter's book of multivariable calculus. Sadly, they do not give any hint. And yes, that was my problem, combining the issue with $log$ as well as the issue with the zero.

Comment: The integrand is odd w.r.t. $x$ (and $y$ and $z$). So, if the integral has a well-defined value, that value will be $0$.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 Could you expand this a bit more please? I didn't quite get it. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: The contribute given to the integral by some point $(x,y,z)$ is counter-balanced by the contribute given by $(-x,-y,-z)$. It is just a pity that the integrand function *is not* integrable over $(\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\})^3$ in any meaningful way.